# JS Callback on taptool for a different plot, using two sources

Tags: javascript, pandas, callback, bokeh

I am trying to use the taptool for other plot callback, I have been wrecking my head around it for a good while. I have two plots and two different sources. Find a minimal example below:

I have a 7 circles plot in a figure, I would like to be able to tap them and use them as callback to other plots. I tried with source.indices, but so far I am stuck at it.

Based on bigredot link.
https://www.py4u.net/discuss/194426

```
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, TapTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
import numpy as np

source_bars = ColumnDataSource({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 1] , 'colnames': ['A', 'B', 'C']})
lines_y = [np.random.random(3) for i in range(3)]
src1 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x= [1, 2, 3],
                                  y=lines_y[0],
                                 y2=lines_y[1],
                                 y3=lines_y[2]))

plot1 = figure(tools = 'tap')
bars = plot1.vbar(x = 'x', top = 'y', source = source_bars, bottom = 0, width = 0.5)

plot2 = figure()
lines = plot2.vbar(x = 'x', top = 'y', source = src1)


code = '''if (cb_data.source.selected.indices.length > 0){
            var data = lines_y.data
            var selected_index = cb_data.source.selected.indices[0];
            lines.data_source.data['y'] = lines_y[selected_index]
            lines.data_source.change.emit(); 
          }'''

plots = row(plot1, plot2)
plot1.select(TapTool).callback = CustomJS(args = {'lines': lines, 'lines_y': src1}, code = code)
show(plots)
```

A different approach with this code, but!!!

```
code3 = """
var col = 'Muara_Teweh_';

// Get data from CDS
var data = source.data;
var data1 = source1.data;

var selected = source.selected.indices;

    // Iterate over all entries in the CDS
    for (var i=0; i<data[col].length; i++){

        if(data[col][i]!=selected){

            data1[selected];
            }
        }
    }

// Save changes to CDS
source.change.emit();
source1.change.emit();
"""
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please share more details. What **exactly** is your question about this code?

Comment: @Nico, I have 7 circles plot in a figure, I would like to be able to tap them and use them as callback to other plots. I tried with source.indices, but so far I am stuck at it. There two different sources btw.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it